# How to access a logged in G+ user's public profile (at least userid)

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm writing a JS app that needs to use the logged in G+ user's public profile picture.

Using the Google+ API I can query for the profile data if I have a userid.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get

However, how do I get the userid of the current logged in user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user will need to connect their Google+ account to your app using the sign-in API.

See: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Once the user has signed in you can get their data using the userId 'me':

```
<button class="g-signin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
        data-clientid="{ YOUR_CLIENT_ID }"
        data-callback="onSignIn"
        data-theme="dark"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        data-width="wide">
</button>

(function() {
    window.onSignIn = function(authResult) {
        if (authResult.access_token) {
            console.log('success');
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){ 
                var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId' : 'me'});
                request.execute(function(response) {
                    console.log('ID: ' + response.id);
                    console.log('Display Name: ' + response.displayName);
                    console.log('Image URL: ' + response.image.url);
                    console.log('Profile URL: ' + response.url);
                });
            });
        } else if (authResult.error) {
            console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult.error);
        }
    };
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript';
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

See: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button#step_5_handling_the_sign-in

Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/3UU7E/

Comment: Thanks @imcg

I'm getting the user logged in OK but when I run your code (above) in the success callback, I'm getting:

 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined "

Do I need a library to support this request?

Any thoughts would be a big help... I just know I'm missing something obvious here?!?

Comment: I've got the quickstart application working, using my clientid.

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript

So i'll try and work it out from there.

Comment: Yup I missed a step (as you've probably figured). Made a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/3UU7E/ Going to update the answer.